# How to handle changing paths in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm at the state where I need to load Images taken from camera/gallery.

I'm creating a directory this way:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var library = Path.Combine(documents, "..", "Library");
var userDirectory = Path.Combine(library, directoryname);
Directory.CreateDirectory(userDirectory);
```

So when I'm saving Images in `userdirectory` and the path to that image I cannot load it after restarting the app.

How would you handle this path problem?

EDIT:
when loading from album this way:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var library = Path.Combine(documents, "..", "Library");
var userDirectory = Path.Combine(library, CurrentUser.Username);
var ImageDirectory = Path.Combine(userDirectory, "ImageDirectory");

string imageuuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string ImageFilename = Path.Combine(ImageDirectory, imageuuid + ".jpg");
```

After that I check if the Image exists and I can see it everytime. 
The Path is:

```
/Users/exampleuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E84B5B50-BA6C-44C2-A755-3A0E96DE20F8/data/Containers/Data/Application/1B287E75-317B-4671-8A16-97F5EA5E27F5/Documents/../Library/userDirectory/ImageDirectory/63408be0-cc49-495f-bc20-e9d90e240597.jpg
```

I'm closing the app completely and restart and the path to the Image changed to:

```
/Users/exampleuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E84B5B50-BA6C-44C2-A755-3A0E96DE20F8/data/Containers/Data/Application/7AACA518-20BE-4276-B29F-9059CAB1B957/Library/userDirectory/ImageDirectory/63408be0-cc49-495f-bc20-e9d90e240597
```

As you see after Data/Application it changes.

After the selection of an Image I save the path. But when I'm loading it can't find the path to that image.

Comment: Have you verified that it is saved correctly?  Have you verified that the file exists before trying to load it?  If you save an image to a path you should be able to load it from that path.  What specifically happens when you try to load the image?

Comment: Yes I tried to take a look if the Image is really in that directory through `Directory.GetFiles()`. I can see that the Image exists but it seems that the path is changing everytime. The userdirectory exists too but the relative path to it is changing... is there a way to start the path from the app directory and not from root?

Comment: the path should not change.  Can you update your question with a specific example of the different paths you are seeing?

Comment: okay I added an example

Comment: the GUID that appears after /Application/ is the ID of your app.  If that changes, it means that the old copy of the app is being deleted (along with it's data) and a new copy is being installed.  Are you deleting your app before re-deploying?

Comment: No I'm just starting the app through the start button (The button isn't named start but the name of the iPhone + iOS version like iPhone 6 iOS 10.3) I'm just closing the app through the double home button press and swipe up. and launching it through visual studio. so that is why the path is changing?

Comment: I'm not aware of any options to automatically do this in iOS, unless they added something in VS2017.  You might look through the iOS project properties dialog and see if there is any likely looking culprit.

Comment: thank you very much! At least I know what that ID is for!